# Tower of Hanoi maximum counts of 100 allowed

Tags: python-3.x

I've recently coded on python3 the famous Tower of Hanoi problem. I would like to ask how to add an additional condition: if there are more than 100 movements, then exit the program and print "Tedious computational power".

```
# Tower of Hanoi problem
print('Tower of Hanoi')

no_discs = int(input('Please input number of discs: '))

column_1 = 1
column_2 = 2
column_3 = 3


def thaphanoi(no_discs, column_1, column_2, column_3):
    if no_discs == 1:
        print("Disc in column {} -> column {}".format(column_1, column_2))
    else:
        thaphanoi(no_discs - 1, column_1, column_3, column_2)
        thaphanoi(1, column_1, column_2, column_3)
        thaphanoi(no_discs - 1, column_3, column_2, column_1)


thaphanoi(no_discs, column_1, column_3, column_2)
print('Program ended')
```

I expect this code to print 7.

Comment: You expect it to print `7` for which value of `no_discs`? It should be for `3`, based on my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Tower of Hanoi problem can be solved with minimum of `(2^n)-1` moves.

That is

```
No of move required for 1 disk -->  1
No of move required for 2 disks -->  3
No of move required for 3 disks -->  7
No of move required for 4 disks -->  15
No of move required for 5 disks -->  31
No of move required for 6 disks -->  63
No of move required for 7 disks -->  127
and so on..
```

So you can calculate number of movements required after getting the number of required.

like,

```
min_moves = math.pow(2, no_discs) - 1
if min_moves > 100: 
  print("Too many moves")
  sys.exit()
```